# How to average every 3rd row in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have column I with "item score". I would like to average every third row and return the value in Column A, which I have labeled "Overall Survey Score".

So the average of I2:I4 would be displayed in A2. The average of I5:I7 would be displayes in A5 and so on until the last row of data available.

I would like stay away from a formula in a cell and do this using VBA. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What *specifically* is preventing you from trying this?  If you don't know any VBA then this is probably not the place to start...

Comment: Well I started to write some code and am just hitting a wall. I don't do it every day, but i do know some...I am stuck on how to average every third row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub getavgs()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 27 Step 3
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = _
(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L" & i).Value + _
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L" & i + 1).Value + _
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L" & i + 2).Value) / 3
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks. I was trying to use the average function in excel and just couldn't wrap my head around how to get it to work. Some tweaking and adding to this and it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula, like so.  In I2 onwards

`=IF(OR(ROW()-2=0,MOD(ROW()-2,3)=0),AVERAGE(OFFSET(I2,0,0,3,1)),"")`